# Oracle DB 19c and java 6

Tags: jdbc, driver, java-6, oracle19c

There is any chance to connect to an oracle DB 19c with java 6?
I see that the connector is only compatible with jdk8
Whats happens if i use ojdbc6 for connect to a oracle DB 19c?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the Oracle [JDBC FAQ](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/faq-jdbc.html) the release `19c` can be used with

```
ojdbc10.jar with JDK10, JDK11
```

or

```
ojdbc8.jar with JDK8, JDK9, JDK11
```

What happens if you use a lower JDK version?

Simple try, I assume you will see an exception while trying to connect `Exception: Connection refused ...`

otherwise (source is same as above) `If it is not listed in the above table then please check with your support channel to check if you are still on the support contract for the older versions.`

Answer (score 2):

Use Oracle 18 ojdc6.jar. Oracle Database JDBC is compatible with multiple previous and later versions of the database. In particular the 18 version of JDBC is compatible and fully supported with the 19 database.